# How to add a class, and get results once complete

Tags: jquery, css

How would i go about using jQuery to add a "selected" class to the LI's in this?
Once all 6 questions have been selected, i would then need to go through the questions and get the selected answer. I have added the Question ID along with the answer ID to each answer which might make it easier to pick up and process later.

```
 <div id="1002" class="question2" style="display: block; ">
   <h1>Question 2</h1>
   <p><i>This is Question 2</i></p>
   <div class="answer-grid">
    <ul class="answer">
        <li id="1002-a1">Answer 1</li>
        <li id="1002-a2">Answer 2</li>
        <li id="1002-a3">Answer 3</li>
    </ul>
   </div>
 </div>
```

This is how i would like it to look...

```
 <div id="1002" class="question2" style="display: block; ">
   <h1>Question 2</h1>
   <p><i>This is Question 2</i></p>
   <div class="answer-grid">
    <ul class="answer">
        <li id="1002-a1" class="selected">Answer 1</li>
        <li id="1002-a2">Answer 2</li>
        <li id="1002-a3">Answer 3</li>
    </ul>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: nothing yet, i am unsure how to do it tbh which is why i am asking for a hand :)

Comment: please define "selected answer".  You have no selectable fields or other inputs in the given markup.

Comment: updated code... basically i want to select a LI and add the class selected to it. i will also need to know how to get the selected li's back so i can pass them over to a webservice.

Comment: you mean you want to _click_ on an LI?  Are these multiple choice, so you can only have one in each group selected?

Comment: How do you expect to select the LI? It seems like you would need a list of radio buttons with the answers next to them or something similar... If you did it that way you could probably then just use form submission to do this all nice and easily... This will also be better from a UI point of view since generally for multiple chocie questions people expect radio buttons or click boxes or something, not just to click some bullet list text. Though don't forget that using `<label>` you can link text to a radio button...

Comment: yeah that is correct. sorry, should of said that really

Comment: thats true @Chris do you have any examples of this? Also how flexible is styling up of the checkboxes? or maybe use a hidden input? can you provide an example of how you would do it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To toggle the `<li>` elements:

```
$('.answer li').on('click', function() {
    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
});
```

To find the selected `<li>` elements:

```
var answers = $('.answer li.selected').map(function() {
    return this.id;
}).get();
```

Comment: mate, you're a f'ing star!!! thanks very much for your help on that :D this worked a treat!

Comment: how would i go about splitting the question ID and answer? so i can then pass it over to a webservice to be checked? `var jsonText = JSON.stringify({ answer: answers });` I have done this so far

Comment: @thatuxguy use `return this.id.split('-')` - you'll get a two element array containing the question ID and answer number

Comment: I made a slight change bringing back the text of the answer selected. how can i bring back the answer and question ID so i can put them into a string? `return "{question:" + this.id + ", answer:" + $(this).html() + "}";` - for some reason the \" does not add the quotes.

Comment: don't try to serialise your own JSON.   Use `return { question: this.id, answer: $(this).text() };`

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend that you use radio buttons in a form for this. That said, <strike>here's a fiddle with the answer I think you are looking for</strike>  there are some good answers here. :-)

Comment: Good point - using siblings() is a lot better. Think I focused too much on the immediate solution.

Comment: @AndersHolmström agreed, your's does work well, but Alnitak's did just what i wanted :) Thank you any way

Answer (score 0):

Here is live example which does work - http://jsfiddle.net/3fPaC/ .

Code -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var count = 0;
    $("li").click(function() {
        if($(this).siblings().hasClass("selected")) {            
            $(this).siblings().removeClass("selected");
            count--;
            $("#result").text("");
        }
        $(this).addClass("selected");    
        var question = $(this).attr("question");
        $("#"+question).addClass("answered");       
        count++;
        if(count == 3) {
            $(".selected").each(function() {
                $("#result").append(" "+$(this).text());
            });
        }     
    });          
});​
```

Also, do not use just numbers as ID, since it can cause problems.

HTML code -

```
<div id="result"></div>
<div id="question1002" class="question2" style="display: block; ">
   <h1>Question 2</h1>
   <p><i>This is Question 2</i></p>
   <div class="answer-grid">
    <ul class="answer">
        <li question="question1002" answer="a1">Answer 1111</li>
        <li question="question1002" answer="a2">Answer 2111</li>
        <li question="question1002" answer="a3">Answer 3111</li>
    </ul>
   </div>
 </div>

 <div id="question1003" class="question2" style="display: block; ">
   <h1>Question 2</h1>
   <p><i>This is Question 2</i></p>
   <div class="answer-grid">
    <ul class="answer">
        <li question="question1003" answer="a1">Answer 1</li>
        <li question="question1003" answer="a2">Answer 2</li>
        <li question="question1003" answer="a3">Answer 3</li>
    </ul>
   </div>
 </div><div id="question1004" class="question2" style="display: block; ">
   <h1>Question 2</h1>
   <p><i>This is Question 2</i></p>
   <div class="answer-grid">
    <ul class="answer">
        <li question="question1004" answer="a1">Answer 122</li>
        <li question="question1004" answer="a2">Answer 222</li>
        <li question="question1004" answer="a3">Answer 322</li>
    </ul>
   </div>
 </div>​
```

You can change the count == 3 to whatever you like. The 3 is the number of questions.